# How to combine 2 values to form a node in Python

Tags: python, csv, graph, nodes

I am using Python to read data from a file and assign the strings in one column to the integers in another column. This is what I have so far:

```
flight_source_graph = {}

with open('flightinfo.csv') as csvfile:
  reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
  next(reader, None)
  for row in reader:
    flight_source = row[0]     #'ABC','XYZ','TWR'
    flight_dep_time = row[2]   #'0','10','7'
    

    #departure information
    if flight_source in flight_source_graph:
      flight_source_graph[flight_source].append(flight_dep_time)
    else:
      flight_source_graph[flight_source] = [flight_dep_time]
 
Output:

{'ABC': ['0', '10', '7'], 'XYZ': ['4','7','10'], 'TWR': ['9','11','15','24']}
```

Now that I have this data showing what's assigned to what, how would I go about transforming it to create a list that looks like this:

```
[('ABC', '0'),('ABC','10'),('ABC','7')]
#Where each of the values in the parentheses () would signify a node
```

Comment: Do you want a list for each key separately, or do you want everything in one?

Comment: Everything in one @Reti43

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way to combine the keys with the list values:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    flight_info = {'ABC': ['0', '10', '7'], 'XYZ': ['4', '7', '10'], 'TWR': ['9', '11', '15', '24']}
    flight_graph = []
    for k, v in flight_info.items():
        for i in v:
            flight_graph.append((k, i))
    print(flight_graph)
    # [('ABC', '0'), ('ABC', '10'), ('ABC', '7'), ('XYZ', '4'), ('XYZ', '7'), ('XYZ', '10'), ('TWR', '9'), ('TWR', '11'), ('TWR', '15'), ('TWR', '24')]
```